# Tem como usar um dialog para abrir tanto pastas quanto arquivos?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arquivo, diretório

Bom, estou usando o `openfiledialog` para abrir arquivos, porém o software necessita receber arquivos ou pastas, porque ele comprimi e zipa (`.zip`) para depois fazer uma cifra simétrica.

Procurei em diversos sites e afins, e não encontrei uma forma de usar o mesmo dialog para abrir ambos tipos.

```
private void btn_criptografar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Abre o dialogo para abrir arquivos e pastas.
        if (openFileCrypt.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBoxShowPath.Text = openFileCrypt.FileName;

            FileStream inStream = File.OpenRead(textBoxShowPath.Text);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é possível no controle padrão, tem que desenvolver um novo que faça isto. Tem um [exemplo](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/29832#432677) de como pode ser em uma biblioteca que trabalha justamente com arquivos zip ([projeto isolado](https://github.com/jkells/folder-browser-dialog-example)).

Outro [projeto que faz o mesmo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44914/Select-file-or-folder-from-the-same-dialog).

Comment: Bom, muito obrigado, eu realmente perdi muito tempo achando que conseguiria fazer por meios nativos.